# Nonparametric Bayesian priors on mean $0$ distributions?

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, prior, nonparametric-bayes

Is there any standard way of putting a prior on the mean $0$ distributions? I'm interested in this from the perspective of robustly modelling the error distribution in a regression. So for instance I have some covariates $X$ and I want to specify $E[Y] = \mu(X | \beta)$ where $\mu(\cdot | \beta)$ is of a prespecified form and $Y$ takes values in $\mathbb R$. A simple solution would be to confound the error distribution with the intercept and use a Dirichlet process mixture, i.e. write $Y_i = \mu(X | \beta) + \eta_i$ where
$$
\eta_i \sim f(\cdot | \theta), \\
\theta \sim F, \\
F \sim DP(\gamma H).
$$
Then I can write $\epsilon_i = \eta_i - E(\eta_i | F)$ and put $\alpha = E(\eta_i | F)$ so that $Y_i = \alpha + \mu(X_i | \beta) + \epsilon_i$. The glitch here is that *I don't want the error distribution to be independent of $X$*. I've had a few ideas on how to fix this up, but they seem round-about and hopefully someone here knows of some mainstream solution.

Comment: Are you willing to impose symmetry as well?  If so, you could construct a DP scale mixture of Normal mean-0 variates for the error term.  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: @jbowman I want the error distribution to depend on $X$, so that doesn't give us what we want immediately. But yes, If I tweak the idea I could do that if I was willing to impose symmetry and unimodality for all realizations of $X$. Actually, that might be a reasonable solution if I was worried about heteroscadasticity but otherwise okay with symmetry and unimodality. I could drop it down to "just" symmetry by setting up the distribution for $\eta$ as above and setting $\epsilon_i = \eta_{i1} - \eta_{i2}$.